# Spring OAuth2 : how to configure column size?

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I am using the [Spring Security OAuth](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security-oauth) legacy project.

Internally, the list of OAuth2 clients is stored in the table `oauth_client_details`. I need one client to be able to store a big redirect URI (column `web_server_redirect_uri`) that exceeds 256 characters.

How can I change the size of that column in Spring ?

Thanks.